# Windows 8 creating 'ghosts' VPN connections

Tags: windows-8, vpn, network-adapter

I have a paid VPN service (StrongVPN), and as I live in university halls I have to connect to the internet through the university's VPN and then connect to StrongVPN. This usually works fine, but sometimes the connection drops and I have to connect to the uni's vpn again, and in rarer occasions to StrongVPN again too.

The problem is that Windows creates these VPN connections you can see on the right of the picture, and it even created them over and over again, duplicating some of them.

When this happens, one or more (the second and fourth) connections will stay "connecting", even after I disconnected it using StrongVPN's dialer application. This means that when I try to connect again to StrongVPN, my whole internet simply drops, and only works again when I disconnect it (creating another "ghost" connection). And because these connections are made dynamically by StrongVPN's dialer, I can't see them when I go to Adapter Settings so I can maybe delete them.

If I restart everything goes back to normal, but as you can see from my taskbar, I usually have loads of relatively heavy applications running, and having to close them all, restart and open them all again to continue my work is just a pain in the ass. So I want to know if someone knows a way to get rid of these connections, without having to restart Windows.
Thanks!

[image: Print screen of networks]

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/476990/new-network-name-created-every-time-i-connect-a-windows-7-machine-to-my-nexus-on

Comment: Thanks, it looks somewhat similar to what I'm experiencing, but at east with me Windows has never prompted me to choose the type of the network (home, work, public), and I think the VPN service acts as a gateway, but I might be wrong as I myself don't fully understand some of these network concepts.