# Why does my PC keep creating new Wi-Fi profiles every time it connects to my access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

As I've already explained in another question (https://superuser.com/posts/comments/2800008?noredirect=1), I use an Oppo A54 5G smartphone as a wireless access point.

I turn off the Wi-Fi hotspot at night, and turn it back on in the morning, to connect my two laptops (both Asus running Windows 10 Pro).

Problem is, I suppose the phone's public IP address must be reset at night, or something like that, because when I turn it back on and my PCs connect to it, they create a new connection, with an incremental number, as in "SSID 5", then "SSID 6" the next time, and so on.

Same in Registry, where I routinely find dozens of Wi-Fi profiles and "Unmanaged Signatures", which I must delete manually. Ditto the extra-profiles.

How can I set one Wi-Fi profile, once and for all? I've already set everything up in secpol.msc, name of the network, location (public vs private), etc... but I keep seeing those new profiles appear after each connection.

One is created for a public network, then I suppose secpol steps in and turns it into a private network, and it adds both to the profile list. Same with the "Unmanaged Signatures".

Since I have 2 PCs that I'm having a hard time connecting to one another, I'm pretty sure this doesn't help, especially if one knows my access point as "SSID 1O" and the other knows it as "SSID 12", for example.

(This is not a duplicate of [New network name created every time I connect a Windows 7 machine to my Nexus One Portable Wi-Fi hotspot](https://superuser.com/questions/476990/new-network-name-created-every-time-i-connect-a-windows-7-machine-to-my-nexus-on) because a) It's been ten years; and b) My phone is dual-SIM, therefore the gateway IP can change, depending on which SIM is handling the data at any given moment.)

One more thing: I've set two scheduled tasks, one at logon that sets whatever Wi-Fi connection I have running to private, and another that pops up every 5 minutes to do the same thing, just in case my Wi-Fi has gone public behind my back. It's probably overkill but who knows.

Comment: is the mac address of the hotspot the same every time you connect to it?

Comment: No, and that's the other mystery: There's one MAC address that shows on both PCs, and that's the one whose profile I've chosen to retain. I can't really understand how or why the phone would change its MAC with every new connection. As you might imagine, it being a smartphone, the Wi-Fi hotspot settings are pretty sparse. I can choose the band (2.4GHz or 5GHz), the security level, and the passphrase, but that's pretty much it. In the Developers Options, I can choose to enable hardware acceleration for the hotspot. It's currently disabled. Could that be a factor?

Comment: I just checked and it's turned off.

Comment: I disabled "Smart 5G" too and enabled hardware acceleration for the hotspot. I live in France by the way.

Comment: FWIW, I re-enabled "Smart 5G" due to the positive impact it has on the phone battery life, and disabled hardware acceleration because it didn't net me anything in terms of solving my problem.

Comment: The first thing that springs to mind is randomised MAC addresses. It doesn't look from this MS post that it's enabled by default on Win11 like it is on most mobile phones these days, but it may be contributory; either on the computers or on the phone itself - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-random-hardware-addresses-in-windows-ac58de34-35fc-31ff-c650-823fc48eb1bc

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't see that option on either PC, but it's there on the phone, in the Dev Options, and it's disabled. On one PC, the network is named "Oppo A54 5G 5", and on the other it's called "Oppo A54 5G 7", and yet, for once, I can RDP from one to the other, at least for now.